# Spring Security: SecurityContextHolder not populating correct user data in production

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am using Spring Boot (version : 1.3.2) along with spring web and security.

**Scenario**: I have an external authentication service, that issues OAuth2 tokens to clients trying to access API's of my spring app. To intercept and understand the token I have followed the configuration mentioned in [this](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt) tutorial. This is a stateless REST Api JWT Token based authentication for spring security.

**Problem**: Things are working for me when I run my app on localhost and try accessing the app from different browsers (incognito) mode. The problem arises when I deploy it to my Ubuntu 12.04 Server. Whenever I am trying to access methods marked @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')") I am getting a 401 although the user is logged in and authorised to use the API.

**Working Case Log from Localhost**:

```
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d531be5
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/error'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - No matches found
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@54d08125
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'com.mycompany.inventory.helpers.UserAuthentication@55ea85d9'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@1d3565e1
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/resources/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/app/login/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/api/**'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/purchaseOrders/get; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Previously Authenticated: com.mycompany.inventory.helpers.UserAuthentication@55ea85d9
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@446e8d44, returned: 1
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Authorization successful
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - /api/purchaseOrders/get reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/api/purchaseOrders/get]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Looking up handler method for path /api/purchaseOrders/get
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Did not find handler method for [/api/purchaseOrders/get]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Looking up handler method for path /api/purchaseOrders/get
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.mycompany.inventory.dto.PurchaseOrderDTO>> com.mycompany.inventory.rest.controllers.PurchaseOrderApiController.getAllPurchaseOrders()]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'purchaseOrderApiController'
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Last-Modified value for [/api/purchaseOrders/get] is: -1
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.mycompany.inventory.rest.controllers.PurchaseOrderApiController.getAllPurchaseOrders(); target is of class [com.mycompany.inventory.rest.controllers.PurchaseOrderApiController]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasAnyRole('ADMIN')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Previously Authenticated: com.mycompany.inventory.helpers.UserAuthentication@55ea85d9
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@6bb04370, returned: 1
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Authorization successful
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@64f555b5] for JPA transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Creating new transaction with name [com.mycompany.inventory.servicesImpl.PurchaseOrderServiceImpl.getPurchaseOrders]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3400e582]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@64f555b5] for JPA transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Participating in existing transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@64f555b5] for JPA transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Participating in existing transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Initiating transaction commit
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@64f555b5]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Written [[]] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@76cde05c]
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Successfully completed request
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Chain processed normally
2016-04-17 10:13:55 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4d531be5
```

As you can see:
**SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'com.mycompany.inventory.helpers.UserAuthentication@55ea85d9'**

The security context in working case is reporting the presence of a user authentication already being present. Even though this works, I am wondering if this is the correct behaviour? Since my configuration is for a stateless session, why should the security context find an existing authentication entry in its context? Is this expected?

**Non-Working Case Log from Server**:

```
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@750475e2
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/error'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - No matches found
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4a77b460
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 122.171.94.145; SessionId: 4094950BB43FBE280B81842F649BA18E; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - /api/purchaseOrders/get at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/resources/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/app/login/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Checking match of request : '/api/purchaseorders/get'; against '/api/**'
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/purchaseOrders/get; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 122.171.94.145; SessionId: 4094950BB43FBE280B81842F649BA18E; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@385462f, returned: -1
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - AuditEvent [timestamp=Sun Apr 17 04:40:19 UTC 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2016-04-17 04:40:19 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.drivojoy.inventory.helpers.StatelessAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(StatelessAuthenticationFilter.java:30) [classes!/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

As you can see: **Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 122.171.94.145; SessionId: 4094950BB43FBE280B81842F649BA18E; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'**

The spring security context is loading an anonymous user in its context. Below is my Filter.

```
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    
        private final TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
        public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
            this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            Authentication authentication = authenticationService.getAuthentication(httpRequest);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
    }
```

I have debugged till this point and found that in all cases, my security context is set with the correct authenticated and authorised user.

Can anyone please help me understand the root cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause guys. Turns out, the JWT token parser was throwing an exception stating:
"JWT must not be accepted before XXX. Current time: XXX"

The time on my Ubuntu Server was 1 min behind than the server that issued the token, due to this, the token validation was failing.

Refer [this code](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/impl/DefaultJwtParser.java#L378) to understand it better.